# VSTO add multiple XML Content into content control

Tags: xml, ms-word, insert, vsto, contentcontrol

hey i searched everything but found nothing on this case. I want to insert multiple XML-contents into a chosen Word content control. My foreach loop overwrites the old XML with each pass. So it effectively only inserts the last XML content from my collection. Is there a way to append XML content in a range instead of replacing it?

```
            foreach (ContentControl cc in targetDoc.ContentControls)
            {
                if (cc.Tag == "X_Placeholder")
                {
                    foreach (var tbContent in textBrickContentList)
                    {
                        cc.Range.InsertXML(tbContent);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: AKAIK, you likely can't in the way explained.i do not see how a CC can contain many XML documents. You could assemble the content of those XMLs into one XML and insert that.

Comment: found the solution, its:
 targetDoc.Range(cc.Range.End, cc.Range.End).InsertXML(tbContent);

Answer (score 0):

found the solution, its:

```
targetDoc.Range(cc.Range.End, cc.Range.End).InsertXML(tbContent);
```